# How to use like query on FullText Index Column

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I have this user table structure.

```
    `users` (
      `id` bigint(20),
      `balance` bigint(20),
      `current_parent` bigint(20),
      `parents` varchar(45),
      `role_id` int
    );
```

There are multiple role hierarchy. I have save all upline role id's comma separated in `parents` column.

This is my table sample data.

[image]

Example 1: Let's say if want to fetch sum of balance of children of parent id 1.

Using `FIND_IN_SET`.

```
select sum(balance) from users where FIND_IN_SET(1, parents);
```

Using `LIKE`

```
SELECT sum(balance) FROM `users`
    WHERE parents like '1,%'
       or parents like '%,1,%'
       or parents = 1;
```

Example 2:
If the parent id is 2.

Using `FIND_IN_SET`.

```
select sum(balance) from users where FIND_IN_SET(2, parents);
```

Using `LIKE`

```
SELECT sum(balance) FROM `users`
    WHERE parents like '2,%'
       or parents like '%,2,%'
       or parents = 2;
```

But above query is taking too much time to execute. Currently user table has 1.5 million records. So I have found solution FULLTEXT search . My question is how can I achieve above query using `FullText`? or any other solution to improve my query performance.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` needs a commalist of values in a string.

Comment: Please provide some sample data that shows a few examples of the hierarchy, and provides the desired result.

Comment: @RickJames I have update the question and provided a example. Please check.

Comment: Is the parent-to-child relationship "many-to-many"?

Comment: No, One to one relationship. There is  a `current_parent` is direct parent.

Comment: Ah,  The `parents` column should be named `ancestors`.

Comment: Yeh that's correct I will alter the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Note the order of arguments and quoting:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', parents)
```

Simpler to write, and probably runs 3 times as fast.  But it does require checking each row.

Comment: Oh that order was wrote by mistake in question. I will edit the question

Comment: I have tried this but it still taking too much time do you have any other solution ?